# Remove numbers conditionally?

Tags: python

I'm sorry if the title isn't very descriptive. I don't exactly know how to sum up my problem in a few words.

Here's my issue. I'm cleaning addresses and some of them are causing some issues.

I have a list of delimiters (avenue, street, road, place, etc etc etc) named `patterns`.

Let's say I have this address for example: `SUITE 1603 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK`

I would like the output to be `SUITE 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK`

Is there any way I could somehow look to see if there are 2 batches of numbers (in this case `1603` and `200`) before one of my patterns and if so, strip the first batch of numbers from my string? i.e remove `1603` and keep `200`.

Update:  I've added this line to my code:

`address = re.sub("\d+", "", address)` however it's currently removing all the numbers. I thought that by putting ,1 after address it would only remove the first occurrence but that wasn't the case

Comment: There are plenty of options but SO is not a code writing service. You could slice the string to get a list and then join only parts of it.

Comment: Use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: @pzp thank you for that suggestion! I've added this line to my code: `address = re.sub("\d+", "", address) ` however it's currently removing all the numbers. I thought that by putting `,1` after address it would only remove the first occurrence but that wasn't the case.

Comment: How many street addresses are you dealing with?  Have you considered using a service such as [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/features)?

Comment: Add your existing code so we can help you debug it properly and understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: So do you want only the last number sequence?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\d+) (\d+)', r'\2', address)`

Comment: We previously used SmartyStreets, however ran into problems with it. I'm dealing with anywhere between 5 and 10 thousand addresses every day. I don't really think posting my code would help much as it's nearly 600 lines, and none of it yet pertains to this issue. I've put a regex that i'm trying to use in the original post, as well as the issue i'm having with it.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski THAT WORKED! Thanks!!! If you'd like to post it as the answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply this replacement *only* when one of your "separator" words is used, and *only* when there are two numbers, you can use a fancier regular expression.

```
import re

pattern = r"\d+ +(\d+ .*(STREET|AVENUE|ROAD|WHATEVER))"
input = "SUITE 1603 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK"
output = re.sub(pattern, "\\1", input)

print(output) #SUITE 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK
```

Comment: Nice one, I'm deleting my answer, missed the part about only the first number. As soon as it gets unaccepted - can't seem to be able to delete it while it's accepted.

Comment: Perhaps you should make the street, avenue, etc. group non-capturing: `(?:STREET|AVENUE|ROAD|WHATEVER)`.

Comment: Would I have to put every one of the patterns in between |'s? Because there's like 28 patterns.

Comment: They're currently in a list named `patterns`.

Comment: @hleggs:  Yes, you'd have to do that.  you could build it using `"|".join(patterns)`.

Comment: Where would that go?

Comment: @hleggs: Something like this: `pattern = r"\d+ +(\d+ .*(" + "|".join(patterns) + "))"`

Comment: That's working, but not with cases where there is something between the two sets of digits, such as `suite 5e 200 park avenue'` How would i change the regex to account for instances where there may be something between the digits?

Comment: @hleggs:  You probably ought to learn regex, but you'd do something like `pattern = r"\d+.* +(\d+ .*(" + ...`.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm reading over the Python regex docs now.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you want to do isn't very clear, but if I understand correctly you want to is to delete the first occurrence of a number sequence?

You could do this without using a *regex*,

```
s = 'SUITE 1603 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK'
l = s.split(' ')
for i, w in enumerate(l):
    for c in w:
        if c.isdigit():
            del l[i]
        break
print ' '.join(l)
```

**Output:** `>>> SUITE 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK`

Comment: I was using the regex that Steven posted above, which works, however there are cases where it doesn't work. For example, if there is anything between the 2 sets of numbers it fails. Would your solution still work?

Comment: @hleggs `SUITE 1603 TESTING 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK'` would return `SUITE TESTING 200 PARK AVENUE SOUTH NEW YORK`

Comment: Okay great. 1 more question. What if there was a case like `xxx 2e 57 east`? I've tested that and it fails. I'm guessing because there is a letter right after the number 2?